# Highlighting Github README.md format in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext2, codehighlighter

I have got README file and I want Sublime to highlight only some pieces of code idented by some "tag", for example:

````
Here is an example of usage

# This should be highlighted
```ruby
  superhero = Superhero.new
  superhero.make_world_better
```
````

or with `[code lang=ruby]` or whatever

Comment: I thinkg you might need a [markdown preview](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview).

Comment: It opens file in browser, but I need just to highlight code right in sublime

Comment: It was just a suggestion of plugin to look for. An [other one](http://ttscoff.github.com/MarkdownEditing/).

Comment: None of the answers really answer the question. I think the desire is for a Github-flavored Markdown syntax highlighting (not preview), to handle scattered language-specific code blocks in the overall markdown file.

Comment: @JorgeArtware absolutely! Thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Lazy answer

<sup>(*for independent fast learners*)</sup>

1. [Install package control for
   sublime-text](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Package%20Control).
2. Once you restarted sublime-text, see "Fast Answer".

---

## Fast answer

<sup>(*for intermediate to advanced sublime-text users*)</sup>

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and `Package Control: Install Package`,
   then install **[`Knockdown`](https://github.com/aziz/knockdown)**.

   *That's it*, now you have a `Set Syntax: Markdown (Github flavored)`
   option right at the reach of your fingertips.

---

## Elaborate answer

<sup>(*powerless to powerfull*)</sup>

### - Installing `Package Control`

1. Open sublime-text.
   <sub>[If you need this functionality available when you edit files on a directory
   owned by root or www-data ( i.e. /var/www/ ) you may want to open sublime with admin
   privileges using `gksu sublime` or similar and repeat every step]</sub>
2. Activate sublime's `console` by pressing <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>
   <sub>[That is CONTROL key plus GRAVE ACCENT key (usually above the TAB key)]</sub>

[image]

3. Copy-paste one of the following options to sublime console's `prompt`.
   <sub>(and press <kbd>enter</kbd>)</sub>:

   If sublime-text 2:

   ```
   import urllib2,os,hashlib; h = '7183a2d3e96f11eeadd761d777e62404' + 'e330c659d4bb41d3bdf022e94cab3cd0'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); os.makedirs( ipp ) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None; urllib2.install_opener( urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib2.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); open( os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by) if dh == h else None; print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h) if dh != h else 'Please restart Sublime Text to finish installation')
   ```

   If sublime-text 3:

   ```
   import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = '7183a2d3e96f11eeadd761d777e62404' + 'e330c659d4bb41d3bdf022e94cab3cd0'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
   ```

[image]

4. Close sublime when the console prints back a message saying "*Please restart Sublime Text to finish installation"* <sub>(usually almost instantaneous)</sub>. Open sublime-text again.
5. Once you restarted sublime-text, the rest is easy, **see "Fast Answer"** <sub>(above)</sub>, or read on.

#### About using Package Control

What you just installed adds a new bunch of commands to your *Palette* and opens the door to a wonderful world of community contributed plugins; a way to extend sublime's functionality by other people or by yourself! (share your code!).
Now lets use it to install `knockdown`.

1. You can access Package Controll simply by pressing <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, and typing `Package Control`, `pc`, `pack` (or anything similar thanks to the fuzzy search feature of the command palette), in this case search the right command by writing `Package Control: Install Package` (or just `pi`).
   <sub>(If something goes wrong you can always *`Remove Package`*)</sub>.

[image]

2. To see all the available packages just <kbd>enter</kbd> or click on it. Sublime will search for all the registered packages and will even check and show for you only the ones that are compatible with your version of sublime-text, you'll have to wait a few seconds.
   <sub>(or less than a second, depending on your internet+computer latency+speed)</sub>.

[image]

3. Now search for and select `knockdown`.

[image]

4. After you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click on it it will take a brief moment to install.

[image]

**That's it**, *it just works*.

## - How to use it you ask?

#### To activate this highlighting in the current loaded buffer:

<sup>(lets say "the open file")</sup>

1. Inside sublime-text and with a .md file opened, press <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> again.
2. Search for `Set Syntax: Markdown (Github Flavored)` and <kbd>enter</kbd> or click on it.
   [image]

#### IF you want to activate for all .md files <sub>(that's a big IF)</sub>

On current version <sub>(Latest Sublime Text 2 releases & any ver 3 release)</sub>:

- Navigate through the following menus: `View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... ->[your syntax choice]`.

On previous versions of sublime:

- Go to a `Packages/User`, create (or edit) a `.sublime-settings` file
  named after the Syntax where you want to add the extensions,
  `Markdown (Github Flavored).sublime-settings` in your case, then
  write there something like this:

```
    {
        "extensions":
        [
            "md"
        ]
    }
```

And then restart Sublime Text

### ... pics, else it shant have come to pass:

<sup>(it totally works! here's the evidence)</sup>
[image]

***presto!***
*You just took one further step to be a sublime-text master, I hope **my answer** helped you*

Answer (score 2):

Your example is describing Markdown structured text

Try

1) Save file with .md extension

2) View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension -> Markdown