# View or Test README files *md in a browser prior to pushing to an online repository for rendering

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, github, markdown

Is there an application or way to render a README.md file in a browser on or offline?   I am learning Markdown, and want instant feedback on some of my writing, as sometimes I forget a space or a blank line to achieve what I want, and it is cumbersome for me to commit and push to GitHub to see its rendering, not to mention the insane number of commits I'm creating for a small change.

Some have suggested setting up a PHP environment in your own server or virtual server, but I don't know how to do that (yet).  I was thinking of an extension that if you opened an *.md file in your browser (I use Chrome predominately, but occasionally FF), it would look the same was as the frame in GitHub.\

I use TextMate and Sublime Text 2 to write the markdown, maybe they have a function I haven't seen/found on their site?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [sublimetext-markdown-preview](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview) package for Sublime Text. It allows you to preview Markdown files on your browser. See the [README.md](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview/blob/master/README.md) for installation instructions.

Answer (score 17):

## Lazy answer

<sup>(*for independent fast learners*)</sup>

- In Atom editor: <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- In Sublime Text: there's a package to highlight Github Flavored MD,
  it renders live as you type within the very same editor, it may not
  look very pretty but at least you can instantly know if you are
  making mistakes. It's called `knockdown`. [See this other question
  and my answer to know more about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17644538/2016708)
  If you wan't to preview the pretty result in a browser before
  publishing you can use the [**`Markdown Preview`**](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Markdown%20Preview) package.

---

## Elaborate answer

<sup>(*sublime-text novice red cross!*)</sup>

### - Installing `Package Control`

1. Open sublime-text.
   <sub>[If you need this functionality available when you edit files on a directory
   owned by root or www-data ( i.e. /var/www/ ) you may want to open sublime with admin
   privileges using `gksu sublime` or similar and repeat every step]</sub>
2. Activate sublime's `console` by pressing <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>
   <sub>[That is CONTROL key plus GRAVE ACCENT key (usually above the TAB key)]</sub>

   [image]
3. Copy-paste one of the following options to sublime console's `prompt`. 
   <sub>(and press <kbd>enter</kbd>)</sub>:

   If sublime-text 2:

   ```
   import urllib2,os,hashlib; h = '7183a2d3e96f11eeadd761d777e62404' + 'e330c659d4bb41d3bdf022e94cab3cd0'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); os.makedirs( ipp ) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None; urllib2.install_opener( urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib2.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); open( os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by) if dh == h else None; print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h) if dh != h else 'Please restart Sublime Text to finish installation')
   ```

   If sublime-text 3:

   ```
   import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = '7183a2d3e96f11eeadd761d777e62404' + 'e330c659d4bb41d3bdf022e94cab3cd0'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
   ```

   [image]
4. Close sublime when the console prints back a message saying "*Please restart Sublime Text to finish installation"* <sub>(usually almost instantaneous)</sub>. Open sublime-text again.
5. Once you restarted sublime-text, the rest is easy, **see "Fast Answer"** <sub>(above)</sub>, or read on.

#### About using Package Control

What you just installed adds a new bunch of commands to your *Palette* and opens the door to a wonderful world of community contributed plugins; a way to extend sublime's functionality by other people or by yourself! (share your code!).
Now lets use it to install `Markdown Preview`.

1. You can access Package Controll simply by pressing <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, and typing `Package Control`, `pc`, `pack` (or anything similar thanks to the fuzzy search feature of the command palette), in this case search the right command by writing `Package Control: Install Package` (or just `pi`).
   <sub>(If something goes wrong you can always *`Remove Package`*)</sub>.

   [image]
2. To see all the available packages just <kbd>enter</kbd> or click on it. Sublime will search for all the registered packages and will even check and show for you only the ones that are compatible with your version of sublime-text, you'll have to wait a few seconds.
   <sub>(or less than a second, depending on your internet+computer latency+speed)</sub>.

   [image]
3. Now search for and select `Markdown Preview`.

   [image]
4. After you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click on it it will take a brief moment to install.

   [image]

   **That's it**, *it just works*.

### - How to use it you ask?

#### To preview your pretty markdown in your default browser:

1. Inside sublime-text and with a .md file opened, press <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> again.
2. Search for `Markdown Preview` and <kbd>enter</kbd> or click on it.
   <sup>(There are many options, I just like github flavor the most :D)</sup>

   [image]

### ... pics, else it shant have come to pass:

<sup>(it totally works! here's the evidence)</sup>
[image]

***presto!***
*You just took one further step to be a sublime-text master, I hope **my answer** helped you*

Answer (score 14):

You can install the python package index pip and then install an application called grip that will serve the .md file on a localhost port. Its very easy once its been installed.

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install grip
```

Then just run:

```
grip
```

In the root directory of the .md file.

Comment: This answer needs to get bumped higher - absurdly simple to use, interacts with Github directly, and works very well.

Comment: I recommend using a virtualenv instead of installing and then this is perfect for me.

Comment: Also available as a package in Ubuntu at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=grip&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all. You can install it straight away with `sudo apt install grip`, and `man grip` will provide most usage information you need. It provides a localhost-type URL that you can open in the browser, showing the rendered md. The view in the browser gets refreshed every time you save the source md file in a text editor.

Answer (score 10):

There's a Chrome plugin to do exactly this.

[Markdown Preview](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-preview/jmchmkecamhbiokiopfpnfgbidieafmd)

> Converts and previews markdown files (.md, .markdown) to HTML right inside Chrome.

Comment: There's also [Markdown Preview Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-preview-plus/febilkbfcbhebfnokafefeacimjdckgl).

Comment: Unfortunately, `Markdown Preview` seems to be a little too finnicky (or just uses a different style than Github-flavored Markdown?) - it wasn't formatting code blocks and lists correctly, even though Github rendered them just fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on OSX / Linux and don't mind the command line, here's a simple script that opens the rendered markdown in a browser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OUTPUT=/tmp/$(basename $1).html
markdown $1 > $OUTPUT
open $OUTPUT
# FIXME: Avoid deleting before opening; possible to use `wait`
# instead?
sleep 1
rm $OUTPUT
```

You might need to substitute the `open` command for something that works on your flavour of Linux, e.g. `firefox $OUTPUT`.

The `sleep 1` is just a hack to prevent the file from being removed before the browser has time to read it; I'm sure a more proficient bash hacker can substitute it with something less ugly ;)

Comment: Resulted in large block of text for me, with lots of newlines apparently missing...

Answer (score 3):

I like the free Chrome app [stackedit](https://stackedit.io/). It lets you create and preview a markdown document at the same time - 2 panes.

Answer (score 2):

@regularjack's answer is probably the way to go, since it is integrated with Sublime Text. However, I just wanted to draw attention to [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is a document converter program, written in Haskell, which converts between numerous file formats, including markdown. Whilst it requires installation there is also a [page to try it out](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try). Whilst not ideal for large documents this site gives you an easy way of copying and pasting markdown and seeing the foramtted result instantly.

Answer (score 2):

Try [MarkView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markview/iaddkimmopgchbbnmfmdcophmlnghkim/) a Chrome extension for editing and viewing markdown file with an outline view, support Github Flavored Markdown table styles and code block syntax highlight.

- Features

  1. Editing and Viewing markdown file in web page style.
  2. Auto reload local file when file is changed  (Post-installation:
     select "Allow access to file URLs" option in chrome://extensions/)
  3. Show outline beside the content in scrollable way
  4. Have buttons for GoTop, ViewSource and GoBottom
  5. Support Github Flavored Markdown table styles and code highlight.
  6. Highlight the code area for programming languages(eg. ```ruby)
  7. Support web pages printing with decent outlook(Chrome->File->Print...)
  8. Responsive: when the window size small than 940px, outline section will 
     automatically hidden; resize bigger than 940px, outline section will display.
  9. MarkView will view all markdown files except those under raw.github.com 
     because that subdomain only displays the source.

Answer (score 0):

FireFox has an editor. It is not perfect to do the editing directly, but it is great to quickly check a change or verify your file before checking in.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/markdown-editor/

Once you installed the Add-On, make sure to go to Customize.. (right click on icons, next to the menu at the top-right) to add the little icon to your bar. Then you will be able to open / close / save, etc. Just like a Desktop application.